# Get unique elements in array without collections

Tags: java

If I use boolean line before for-loop, I am not getting the required Output.
Can someone explain this code to me. This code is to get unique elements in array without Collections. Someone explain it deeply. This code works but I need explanation

```
   public class unique_array {

        public static void getUnique(int[] arr)

        {
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {
                boolean flag = false;
                for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                    if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                    {
                        flag=true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(!flag)
                {
                 System.out.println("unique element are: "+arr[i]);     
                }
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] arr = {1,2,4,1,4,1,5,8,10};
            unique_array.getUnique(arr);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Would you please edit and make the title more appropriate? For example:  *Get unique elements in array without Collections*

Comment: @RamanSahasi Done.

Comment: What do you mean with "unique"? Do you want every Value printed exactly once or every Element that appears exactly once to be printed?

Comment: @IvoVidovic Every element to be printed once

Comment: @chŝdk Exactly why ?? can you explain the working of code

Comment: You have 2 for loops. Which one do you mean in your first sentence? The `boolean flag` statement is in the right place before the `for j` (but inside the `for i`) loop.

Comment: I guess that this program is used to get the unique element of an array but it is not well coded (as it is coded it it has no purpose )

Comment: @raul1ro i want to know why boolean is initialised after first for loop, why can't before for loop

Comment: @YashwanthRK because if you will initialise it before the first loop, it will be `false` only once, and won't be updated if an element is found and it's set to `true`.

Comment: @chŝdk oh i see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to answer with in code

```
    public class unique_array {
    public static void getUnique(int[] arr){
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) ***// This is Outer Loop Run once will choose each element once for comparing  in arr[i]***
        {
            boolean flag = false;  ***// Here flag is Initializing every time to false for new Comparing loop below*** 
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++) ***// this is comparing loop for run for every selected arr[i] for each element is unique or not*** 
            {
                if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                {
                    flag=true; ***//when selected item from outer loop found in array it will break***
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!flag) ***// if loop completed and flag remains false***
            {
             System.out.println("unique element are: "+arr[i]);      
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,2,4,1,4,1,5,8,10};
        unique_array.getUnique(arr);

    }

}
```

Comment: Finally i understood.

Answer (score 1):

It does work like this because you are declaring the `boolean` and setting its value to `false` at the beginning of the loop. And then you set it to `true` only when the condition below is met. If you declared the `boolean` before the `for` loop, you only set the `boolean` to `false` once, and when it once becomes `true`, you never set it to `false` again. It would also work if you declared the `boolean flag;` before the `for` loop and then inside the `for` loop you call `flag = false;`

Comment: oh well explained

Answer (score 0):

1. First `for`: Iterates over all Elements in the array and apply the other steps to every element.
2. You prepare a boolean flag and set it to indicate that the element was not found yet. Note that the boolean flag is initialized here, before the second for loop, because that way it is resetted to the desired "not found yet" state at the beginning for each iteration of the outer loop.
3. second `for`: Iterate over all elements up to but excluding the currently considered element by the outer loop in the array and check for same values. If the values are the same, set the flag to indicate that the value was already found once (and printed as we will see later) and hence the loop can be exited (`break;`)
4. If the flag is indicating that the value was found already (== true), do not print it again, but if the flag says it wa not found/printed before, print it.